# Equivalent of gdal_translate's "-a_scale"-option in pythons gdal.Translate?

Tags: python, gdal

When using `gdal_translate` on the command-line, there is an option to set a scale factor without modifying pixel values using the `a_scale` option (see [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html)).

I want to use this option in Python, e.g. like this:

```
ds = gdal.Translate(fp_out, correctedImage, a_scale = 0.01)
```

But I don't see the options listed in the docstring of `gdal.TranslateOptions` and so the above doesn't work:

```
  options --- can be be an array of strings, a string or let empty and filled from other keywords.
  format --- output format ("GTiff", etc...)
  outputType --- output type (gdalconst.GDT_Byte, etc...)
  bandList --- array of band numbers (index start at 1)
  maskBand --- mask band to generate or not ("none", "auto", "mask", 1, ...)
  width --- width of the output raster in pixel
  height --- height of the output raster in pixel
  widthPct --- width of the output raster in percentage (100 = original width)
  heightPct --- height of the output raster in percentage (100 = original height)
  xRes --- output horizontal resolution
  yRes --- output vertical resolution
  creationOptions --- list of creation options
  srcWin --- subwindow in pixels to extract: [left_x, top_y, width, height]
  projWin --- subwindow in projected coordinates to extract: [ulx, uly, lrx, lry]
  projWinSRS --- SRS in which projWin is expressed
  strict --- strict mode
  unscale --- unscale values with scale and offset metadata
  scaleParams --- list of scale parameters, each of the form [src_min,src_max] or [src_min,src_max,dst_min,dst_max]
  exponents --- list of exponentiation parameters
  outputBounds --- assigned output bounds: [ulx, uly, lrx, lry]
  metadataOptions --- list of metadata options
  outputSRS --- assigned output SRS
  nogcp --- ignore GCP in the raster
  GCPs --- list of GCPs
  noData --- nodata value (or "none" to unset it)
  rgbExpand --- Color palette expansion mode: "gray", "rgb", "rgba"
  stats --- whether to calculate statistics
  rat --- whether to write source RAT
  xmp --- whether to copy XMP metadata
  resampleAlg --- resampling mode
  callback --- callback method
  callback_data --- user data for callback
```

Any ideas on how to get this option to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a workaround could be to read the source code of gdal_edit.py https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_edit.py and edit the scale in the same way with your own script

```
 if scale:
        for i in range(ds.RasterCount):
            ds.GetRasterBand(i + 1).SetScale(scale[i])

    if offset:
        for i in range(ds.RasterCount):
            ds.GetRasterBand(i + 1).SetOffset(offset[i])
```

But by looking at the C++ source code of gdal_translate_lib https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdal_translate_lib.cpp#L2789 it looks like the option should be `"-a_scale"` instead of `"a_scale"` that you used.

Comment: Thanks,  you are right. I can indeed just pass a `gdal.Dataset` (instead of a path) to `gdal.Translate` and add the scale factors to the bands beforehand like you suggest.